# Replacing backslash with double backslash or forward slash in LPSTR filepath

Tags: c++, winapi, openfiledialog, wchar-t

I am trying to post a message to the WIN32 API to open a WAV File. I can do this by setting the LPARAM parameter to L"C:/path/file.wav" This works excelent! However, I have been trying to use a dialogbox to generate a string to a filepath. The OpenFileDialog function can return the selected filepath as a LPSTR datatype, which sounds perfect! However, this filepath is recognized as a windows filepath, thereby consisting of backslashes. Since these backslashes are not escaped or replaced for a forward slash, the compiler starts crying due to an incorrect formed universal character name. Therfore, it seems trivial to replace all the \ in the LPSTR filepath for \ or /. I have been trying to do this in several ways but nothing seems to work.

```
wchar_t* SelectAudioFile(HWND windowHandle) {
    OPENFILENAME ofn;      // common dialog box structure
    char szFile[260];      // buffer for file name

    // Initialize OPENFILENAME
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = windowHandle;
    ofn.lpstrFile = (LPWSTR)szFile;

    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);

    ofn.lpstrFilter = L"Waveform Audio File Format (*.wav)\0*.wav\0";

    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

    // Display the Open dialog box.

    if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn)==TRUE) {
        CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile,
            GENERIC_READ,
            0,
            (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            (HANDLE) NULL);
        MessageBox(windowHandle,ofn.lpstrFile,0,0);
    }

     //Here the backslash should be escaped or replaced.

    const wchar_t * currentPath = ofn.lpstrFile; //This is a LPSTR 
    wchar_t * newPath;
    int filePathLength = sizeof(currentPath);

    for (int i=0; i < filePathLength; i++) {
        if (currentPath[i] == "\\") {
            newPath[i] = "\\\\";
        } else {
            newPath[i] = filePath[i];
        }
    }
    return newPath;


}
```

The following line would post a message telling it to open a certain file at a path

```
PostMessageW(hwnd, WMA_OPEN, 0, (LPARAM)SelectAudioFile(hwnd));
```

Thus replacing the LPARAM with a static filepath works!

How should I replace the backslashes in the filepath?

Thanks a million times!

Comment: This problem really doesn't make much sense to me. You do not have to escape backlashes in strings returned by API functions. That is only required for string *literals*. The string returned in `OPENFILENAME.lpstrFile` by `GetOpenFileName` can be used directly, without modification. It is guaranteed to be a valid path to a file. More likely, the compiler error messages are the result of a mismatch between wide and narrow character types. Are you sure that `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` are both defined for your build? I notice that you're calling the `W` version of *some* APIs, but not *all* of them

Comment: When I directly use the returned string, the console does not give any errors. But the wav file is not played! However, when I give enter a filepath by hand with the forward slash it does start playing. Thus, you would think: the function doesnt return the string!? This argument is invalidated when I print it in a messagebox. However, when I choose to print it in a console by means of wcout << L"The path is " << returnedLPWSTR << L"\n"; the path is empty.

Comment: Perhaps changing from a LPWSTR to LPCWSTR would do the job!? But how can one do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. you are mixing Ansi and Unicode incorrectly.
2. you are returning a pointer to a local buffer that you have not allocated any memory for.
3. you are using `PostMessage()` to asynchronously post a local buffer that may go out of scope and become invalid before the message gets processed by the window.
4. you are posting the message even if `GetOpenFileName()` fails or is canceled.

Try this instead:

```
bool SelectAudioFile(HWND windowHandle, wchar_t *audioFile, int maxAudioFile)
{
    OPENFILENAMEW ofn = {0};

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = windowHandle;
    ofn.lpstrFile = audioFile;
    ofn.nMaxFile = maxAudioFile;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = L"Waveform Audio File Format (*.wav)\0*.wav\0";
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

    if (GetOpenFileNameW(&ofn))
    {
        MessageBoxW(windowHandle, audioFile, 0, 0);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

```
wchar_t szAudioFile[MAX_PATH+1] = {0};
if (SelectAudioFile(hwnd, szAudioFile, MAX_PATH))
    SendMessageW(hwnd, WMA_OPEN, 0, (LPARAM)szAudioFile);
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <string>

std::wstring SelectAudioFile(HWND windowHandle)
{
    OPENFILENAMEW ofn = {0};
    wchar_t szFile[MAX_PATH+1] = {0};

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = windowHandle;
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = L"Waveform Audio File Format (*.wav)\0*.wav\0";
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

    if (GetOpenFileNameW(&ofn))
        MessageBoxW(windowHandle, szFile, 0, 0);

    return szFile;
}
```

```
std::wstring audioFile = SelectAudioFile(hwnd);
if (audioFile.length() > 0)
    SendMessageW(hwnd, WMA_OPEN, 0, (LPARAM)audioFile.c_str());
```

Comment: in the alternate solution: shouldn't `szFile` be declared `static`?

Comment: @Edward No, the contents of the local `szFile` buffer will be copied into a `std::wstring` object automatically. That's the whole point of using the C++ string class: you don't have to manual memory management anymore.

Comment: @CodyGray: you're right, I missed the return type of the function -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Cody Gray that you need escape backlashes only for string literals and that you seem to be mixing Unicode and non-Unicode characters in your code; if your project uses the Unicode character set, you need to change the following:

- `szFile` should be of type `wchar_t` (always watch out when you manually cast types!)
- `ofn.nMaxFile` should be assigned `_countof(szFile)` instead of `sizeof()`
- the call to `CreateFile()` seems to be unnecessary
- `filePathLength` should be assigned `strlen(currentPath)` instead of `sizeof(currentPath)`
- if you are returning the pointer to `szFile[]`, `szFile` needs to be declared static or defined as a global variable outside the function

Replacing `\` by `/`: `newPath` is a local pointer, you are not allocating memory for it and then returning this value, so even if you declared it as `wchar_t newPath[_MAX_PATH]`, the memory address will be invalid when the function returns -- better to just replace the value of `currentPath`.